# Who executes the python codes in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to spark and have a small doubt in spark.
If I write some pyspark code which has some python code as shown below

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
print("Current Time =", current_time)
df = spark.read.format("csv").option("delimiter", ",").load('countries.csv')
df = df.withColumn('C_DT',lit(current_time))
print("new column added")
```

here does the executor run the datetime.now or each executor run the command. 
who runs the print commands, executor or the driver.

Comment: [my understanding] - what you have here is the driver program. So the driver runs these instructions, strictly speaking. But some of those instructions lead to jobs that the driver asks workers to perform (and it sends the appropriate code for that to them). So the answer is 'both do the work', but it's the driver that "runs" this program. The actual answer is long (and your cluster mode may change the answer too)

Comment: the spark is in cluster mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both print commands and `datetime.now()` are executed in Spark driver. The `current_time` will be passed to executors on next *action* command to actually add it to DataFrame.
At the time of `print("new column added")` only `df`'s schema has changed, and there was no actual work done.

Comment: Thanks.. Just a small query as per my understanding, spark driver will send the code (DAG) to each executor to be executed. How does spark driver knows that the withColumn has been completed and it has to execute the print. Is there any mechanism through which executer tells the driver on the same.

Comment: @SnehasishDas Spark has a lazy evaluation concept, in which transformations are stored until "action" (like "show" or "write") comes along.  Only when action will be triggered, driver will communicate with executors and actually add the column.
You can read here about lazy evaluation - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-operations

If it answers your question, please mark the answer as accepted, thanks!